# How to access other property value from function as object property value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
var ali = {   firstname: 'ali', 
            say_hi: function(firstname) { 
            alert("Greetings " + firstname + ", you are talking to " + this.firstname + "!"); 
   } 
}; 

var some_ref = ali.say_hi; 
some_ref("Sabir");
```

It alerts:

```
Greetings Sabir, you are talking to undefined!
```

But I want this:

```
Greetings Sabir, you are talking to ali!
```

I think `self.firstname` refers to window object so it gives undefined.

Can anyone please help me understand what the problem is in this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is issue in this and how to solve

The value of `this` depends on how the function is **called**. By assigning the function to a variable and calling it as `f()`, `this` will refer to the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode). Since there is no global variable with name `firstname`, `this.firstname` will resolve to `undefined`.

If you want `this` to refer to a specific object, you can [**`.bind`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function:

```
var some_ref = ali.say_hi.bind(ali);
```

To learn more about `this`, have a look at some of the many internet references:

- [MDN - this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [YDKJS - this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)
- [Eloquent JavaScript - Methods](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_fkrGgDyRWc)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)

Answer (score 1):

To understand why it is returning `undefined` instead of `ali`, you have to understand **JavaScript binding**.

If you are accessing a method through a reference instead of directly through its owner object, as you are doing, the method loses its implicit binding, and `this` stops referencing its owner object and goes back to its default binding, meaning the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode).

Ultimately, what matters is the manner in which the function is invoked.

See below for more information (there are exceptions, but it can be generally summarized as the following):

> **[Breakdown from YDKJS: Determining `this`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#determining-this)**
>
> Now, we can summarize the rules for determining this from a function call's call-site, in their order of precedence. Ask these questions in this order, and stop when the first rule applies.
>
> 1. Is the function called with new (**new binding**)? If so, this is the newly constructed object.
>
>    - var bar = new foo()
> 2. Is the function called with call or apply (**explicit binding**), even hidden inside a bind hard binding? If so, this is the explicitly specified object.
>
>    - var bar = foo.call( obj2 )
> 3. Is the function called with a context (**implicit binding**), otherwise known as an owning or containing object? If so, this is that context object.
>
>    - var bar = obj1.foo()
> 4. Otherwise, default the this (**default binding**). If in strict mode, pick undefined, otherwise pick the global object.
>
>    - var bar = foo()

Note: In ES6, `this` is the **lexical `this`** for fat arrow functions `=>` and with object short hand notation (e.g., `sampleMethod() {}`), meaning that `this` takes on the outer context as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `this` just `ali.firstname` it will work fine

```js
var ali = {
  firstname: 'ali',
  say_hi: function(firstname) {
    alert("Greetings " + firstname + ", you are talking to " + ali.firstname + "!");
  }
};
var some_ref = ali.say_hi;
some_ref("Sabir");
```

Comment: what was problen with 'this' keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use object constructors to avoid repeating the `var ali = ...` code when you make new people. I am basing the following code on [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html).

```js
function Person(firstname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
}

Person.prototype.say_hi = function(greeter_name) {
  alert("Greetings " + greeter_name + ", you are talking to " + this.firstname + "!");
}

var ali = new Person("Ali");

ali.say_hi("Sabir");
```

Comment: While this is certainly useful, it doesn't explain the issue the OP has.

Comment: `this.propertyName` is typically used in constructors, so I rewrote what the OP intends to do with a constructor.

Comment: But you completely ignored the `var some_ref = ali.say_hi; some_ref("Sabir");` issue, which would still be an issue with your solution.

Comment: I edited my answer, I merely reshuffled the function assignment to a direct call. They both work. His issue was with the use of `this`.

Comment: I'm confused now... your update has the exact same issue the OP is complaining about in the question. Again, how does this solve the OP's issue?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Only worked when I first posted the answer. I wasn't paying attention.